# Why do miners mine testnet transactions

Tags: mining, testnets, reward, block-reward

When I perform an ether-transfer transaction on testnet, some of my ether gets deducted as transfer fees.

But as its not a real ether and has `0` value, how does it profit the miners who mine that transaction?

If they can get real ether as reward by mining `MainNet-Transactions` then why do they waste their time and hardware to mine testnet transactions?

Please forgive me, I might be missing a major point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't provide any value but for developpement we need this testnet.
So devs are [mining](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#mining) on testnet at least to validate their own transactions, but also others. It's a sort of gift to the community as providing code or helping test new versions.

The main benefit for a developper to mine on testnet is to have access to Ether on the testnet. Without testnet Ether you can't create contracts or interact with them.

You can also use faucets that mines testnet Ether and gives you these testnet Ether for free.

Comment: I'm not able to resemble this answer to my question. What I'm asking is, how miners get a reward to mine testnet transactions? What's in there for them? If they can get real ether as reward by mining `mainnet-transactions` then why do they mine testnet transactions?

Comment: They did answer your question. You asked why miners mine on testnets, he said because they're developing on the testnet and need it mined, or they're doing it altruistically for the community. Note that most testnets can be mined on cpu because there is very little competition.